# How to programming website with php in a modularized way?

Tags: php, html, layout

I am developing a website that many pages share the same header/footer/sidebar/topbar.

Say I have three pages: `one/index.php`, `second/index.php`, `third/index.php`. They all share the same header/footer/sidebar.

The problem is where should I put the header/etc and its corresponding css file, since a piece of html code could not import css file.

What's a good way to modularize php/html page? Is there any good tutorial?

Comment: A piece of HTML can call external CSS using <link> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you may want a MVC framework and a template engine. Check out CodeIgniter, or TinyMVC with Smarty. Call external stylesheets with:

```
    <LINK href="special.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Thank for mentioning the framework. I have never thought and used framework before, it's maybe a right time to start learn.

Comment: no problem, once you get the hang of it, you'll never go back

Comment: The only problem now is the path of the css is relative to the require callee php file, but not the required html file.

Comment: can just set to absolute with <LINK href="/path/to/special.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) statement to insert your header/footer/sidebar files where they need to be inserted in your other PHP pages.